WooCommerce Migration | Variable Product aren't imported
TL;DR : WC Variable product aren't imported corrrectly with each migration method
I'm having an issue when importing variable products.
I used some methods to import them: WooCommerce Import/Export CSV; Wordpress XML Import/Export, Plugins...
No stock and no variations imported for each variable product. (But all variation fields are filled on the export CSV)
Simple products are correctly imported

First all attributes/categories bust be there before importing variable product.

They're already imported

Test with the example csv files that comes with every install of Woo - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/sample-data/sample_products.csv . Use the default woo importer and see if all come ok which may tel you something in the file is not correct. Another option is to cut your csv to smaller batches to see if the issue is not timing out or something of that kind - server issue.

The sample file worked, I think the export csv file is corrupted, idk how to make it working. I have many fields to add in the new database

Default Woo importer will import only woo fields. The rest data will be ignored. You need plugin like WP all import for this job. Or copy website and work on that copy ?

Plugins like WP All Import doesn't work in my case. I also tested plugins from WebToffee,  but no one want to make the job this time :-/

Did you export the file with wp all export or woo export ? wp all export offers batches so export like 10 products and test with them.

both. Idk why they don't work. I will try to downgrade woocommerce version to know if this method work

Ok, i got a "429 too many requests" error and this result at the end of importation : "All (660), Published (81), Drafts (4)"

Solved !
I checked error logs, it's due to a 429 error from the old website during the migration.
The solution is to disable the host spam protection, themes and plugins from the old website.
